# Can I turn off Discussion Forum Administrator notifications?

Tags: forum, notification, discussion

I'm set as the Administrator on a client's discussion forum. Certain employees are set as moderators and receive email notifications. I don't want to receive the notifications as the administrator. Any way to turn this off? I searched through the menus and couldn't find anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the "New Topics" / "New Reply" notifications? If so, just don't specify your email in "Admin Notification Preferences" when you "Edit" the forum in question in the CP. See screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Bjorn, my email isn't in there. I have added a couple email addresses of my client in there.

Comment: Then it's probably the "webmaster email" setting - I'd just change that email to your clients'. https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/email_configuration.html or https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/system_configuration_overrides.html

Comment: Thanks Bjorn, this is probably the answer. It's a slow board so I'll have to wait a few days to see if it worked. If you update your answer above with this info I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks!